# ng-click works only after filtering by typing into a field

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-click

I want to add to dir Paginate control filtering.

```
  <tr dir-paginate="advert in adverts |orderBy:propertyName:reverse | filter: searchAdvert | itemsPerPage: pageSize">
```

I have categoryId property in a model of my data and I want to filter it by using a choosing one of 4 buttons, so I wrote the code like:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"   ng-click="applyFilter(3)">Items</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="applyFilter(4)">Accomodation</button>
```

And in my controlles is:

```
$scope.applyFilter = function(object) {
    $scope.searchAdvert.categoryId = object;
}
```

});

However, it does not work. It worked for me only if I added following textbox:

```
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search by Category" ng-model="searchAdvert.categoryId" />
```

And if I write e.g. 1, then I can use the buttons and they work.
I want to make it work without thix textbox ( only buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your applyFilter to:

```
$scope.applyFilter = function(object) {
    if(!$scope.searchAdvert)
       $scope.searchAdvert = {};

    $scope.searchAdvert.categoryId = object;
}
```

Your current code is trying to set a value `categoryId` on a null object. Your textbox example creates the $scope.searchAdvert object internally and allows the `categoryId` to be bound.

Comment: Another question: now I have also `<input type="text" placeholder="Search Advert" ng-model="searchAdvert" />` - it is normal input field. Why when I use the buttons in this field shows `[object Object]` and how to prevent it

Comment: @Pawel If you are using the $scope.searchAdvert object to store filter info, you can't bind a textbox to it directly. If you want to bind to an object, you would be better suited to use a dropdown/select box.